# How to modify a dbus service's "Exec" line without losing the changes in case of upgrade

Tags: d-bus, gnome-keyring

I'm facing a ugly problem with my system. my login manager (LightDM) is starting gnome-keyring-daemon at login successfully and unlocking my keyring as it should (**EDIT:** Everything via PAM).

The thing is, I get gnome-keyring-daemon started with just one component: `secrets`, but I need all these: `pkcs11`, `secrets`, `ssh`, and `gpg`. I don't know why the latter is not the default, I neither know if I should report this to the package maintainer.

The file `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.secrets.service` defines how gnome-keyring-daemon should run:

```
[D-BUS Service]
Name=org.freedesktop.secrets
Exec=/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --foreground --components=secrets
```

I could just edit it on Emacs and problem solved, but, that's dirty and my changes will be gone for the next upgrade of the gnome-keyring package.

So, the question is: How do I change the `Exec` line of that service while preventing this to be lost in the next system upgrade? Is there a way to enable custom services and disable those services that comes by default?

The relevant packages and their versions installed on my system.

```
$ LC_ALL=C pacman -Qi dbus gnome-keyring lightdm | egrep "(Name|Version)"
Name           : dbus
Version        : 1.8.8-1
Name           : gnome-keyring
Version        : 3.12.2-1
Name           : lightdm
Version        : 1:1.12.0-1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found a way to solve this issue. This not address my question directly, but solves the issue that pushed me to ask here.

## The problem

as it was, gnome-keyring wasn't unlocking my GPG keys, so I was asked for the password of my GPG key every time I login (because Emacs reads a .gpg file for configuration), all my passwords were available after login so offlineimap didn't complain about don't be able to get the passwords of my e-mail account at all when working.

I tried then to start gnome-keyring-daemon from the `.xprofile` (which is read by LightDM, other DM may read different files) in this way:

```
#!/bin/bash

eval $(gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=gpg,pkcs11,secrets,ssh)
export GPG_AGENT_INFO SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

After rebooting (I like this best than logout and login again) and login, I wasn't asked for my GPG key password, however offlineimap was complaining about not being able to get the passwords of my e-mail accounts. Running seahorse I notice that there is no **Passwords** section.

## The solution

After fighting for few hours and trying many different combinations (one of them, showing the **Passwords** section but with the folder Login locked!) I found out what was the correct solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

source /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/30-dbus  # You need a dbus session, duh
eval $(gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=gpg,pkcs11,secrets,ssh)
export GPG_AGENT_INFO SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

Done. problem solved. el es fin, muchachos.

**EDIT:** Beware, your gnome-keyring-daemon may issue more environment variables for you to export. To be sure you don't need more than `GPG_AGENT_INFO` or `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` run `gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=gpg,pkcs11,secrets,ssh` from your shell and add more variables to `export` sentence according.

Please note that LightDM is still starting gnome-keyring-daemon thanks to its PAM configuration and I **wouldn't** recommend you to change such configuration. **However**, if you find yourself inserting your password after login to unlock something on gnome-keyring, it might be because LightDM is not providing your password to it. I did this addition to LightDM PAM module `/etc/pam.d/lightdm`:

```
auth       optional    pam_gnome_keyring.so try_first_pass
```

The addition was the `try_first_pass` thing (reading [The Linux-PAM System Administrators' Guide](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/Linux-PAM_SAG.html) is not a bad idea), in my system LightDM don't have that parameter included.

This is how I solved my problem with Gnome Keyring!

Answer (score 1):

(answering the question in the title as it is useful by itself)

According to the [documentation of D-Bus](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#message-bus-starting-services),

> If two .service files in different directories offer the same service name, the one in the higher-priority directory is used: for instance, on the system bus, .service files in /usr/local/share/dbus-1/system-services take precedence over those in /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services.

Also, according to the manpage of dbus-daemon,

> On Unix, the standard session service directories are:
>
> - `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/dbus-1/services`, if `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` is set
> - `$XDG_DATA_HOME/dbus-1/services`, where `XDG_DATA_HOME` defaults to `~/.local/share`
> - `directory/dbus-1/services` for each `directory` in `XDG_DATA_DIRS`, where `XDG_DATA_DIRS` defaults to `/usr/local/share:/usr/share`
> - `${datadir}/dbus-1/services` for the `${datadir}` that was specified when dbus was compiled, typically `/usr/share`

So, in your case, you could copy the service file to `~/.local/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.secrets.service` and modify it to your requirements. The original file will then be ignored completely.